# read_csv columns encoding

Tags: python, csv, encoding, pandas

I am quite new to python.

I am trying to automate some data analysis of building energy consumption data using python.
I am using `python 2.7.3`, `pandas 0.12`, `Canopy with qtconsole`

These are the steps I am following:

1. Paste the data from my simulation software in excel
2. Export to csv from Excel
3. Import the csv in a pandas `dataframe`
4. Perform my analysis

In the interactive console I write the following code

```
import pandas as pd
rooms = pd.read_csv('IES Results - Rooms.csv', index_col='Room # (Real)')
systems = pd.read_csv('IES Results - Systems.csv',index_col='Room #')
all_values = pd.concat([rooms,systems],axis=1)
all_values = all_values.T.drop_duplicates().T
columns = [u'Room ID',u'Room Name',u'Floor Area (m²) (Real)',u'Volume (m³) (Real)']
selected_values = all_values[columns]
```

Unfortunately I get the following error

`KeyError: "[u'Floor Area (m\\xb2) (Real)' u'Volume (m\\xb3) (Real)'] not in index"`

As you can see all the columns with a superscript are not interpreted correctly and they cannot be found in the `dataframe`.

When I write

`all_values.columns`

The columns headers are displayed correctly in the `IPython` console. I then copy and paste the values I am interested in to create the 'columns' list to pass to `'selected_values = all_values[columns]'`

I have done quite a bit of research, but I cannot get my head around it.

I have tried to specify various encoding but I am not really understanding what it is happening.

I have been stuck for more than a day.

Can you please help?

Comment: To get from an encoding (in the csv file) to Unicode (in the program) you need to use the `encoding` keyword argument to `pd.read_csv` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Comment: Hi, I'd like to try and reproduce this, but I can't get Excel to export to CSV with superscripts. Can you look at your CSV file and let me know how the superscripts are displayed there?

Comment: Hi, I just 'save as' csv. I have tried to open the file with Notepad++ and I see the superscripts. I am using Excel 2010 in Windows 7 64bit

Comment: I think that the problem is the copy and paste that I use to create the 'columns' list. If I print the list after I have created it I lose the superscripts.

Comment: @bernie I have tried to use the keyword, but there is no difference. I have saved the csv in UTF-8 from Libre and used encoding='UTF-8'.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, If I was doing something like this,

1)Get rid of Excel.  - Do you need it. Why does your simulation program not dump the data it self? If it can't in stead of pasteing to to Excel, paste it to a txt file and parse it from Python

2)Get rid of super script -  Do you really need the superscript ? I would remove those, at least in my analysis stage, when some sort of presentation is needed, I would restore those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to past the content in a csv file created with Notepadd++. Same result.

Comment: Can we see an example of the file content? Did you try stripping the superscript?

Comment: No, I havent'. I want to minimize the manual intervention on the file. This is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0tgb4hzg9aokis/IES%20Results%20-%20SO.csv

Comment: I would strip them in python prior to using pandas

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of testing I have discovered that the problem was in the copy and paste that I was using to create 'columns'.

Compare the difference.

This 'columns' is created with copy and paste

```
columns_cp = [u'Room ID',u'Room Name',u'Floor Area (m²) (Real)',u'Volume (m³) (Real)']
columns_cp
Out[29]: 
[u'Room ID',
 u'Room Name',
 u'Floor Area (m\xb2) (Real)',
 u'Volume (m\xb3) (Real)']
```

As you can see the formatting is gone. m\xb2 and m\xb3 are not correct.

A better way to do it is the following

```
columns = [all_values.columns.tolist()[i] for i in [0,1,8,11]]
```

Where 0,1,8,11 are the columns I am interested in.
This is the output of columns

```
columns
Out[30]: 
['Room ID',
 'Room Name',
 'Floor Area (m\xc2\xb2) (Real)',
 'Volume (m\xc2\xb3) (Real)']
```

As you can see the encoding has not been lost, indeed:

```
selected_values = all_values[columns]
In [32]: selected_values
Out[32]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 288 entries, 0 to 457
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Room ID                   288  non-null values
Room Name                 288  non-null values
Floor Area (m²) (Real)    288  non-null values
Volume (m³) (Real)        288  non-null values
dtypes: object(4)
```

It works as I expected and superscript are not lost.

Cheers